# Why does my trivia app on code.org pause on event china button?

Tags: javascript, code.org, app-lab

My trivia app on code.org it keeps pausing on event china button. Why?

Someone else in my class had similar code for the button and no error is showing up in the debug console. the way it is pausing is also how you pause the program in the debug console despite me not touching it, though it does continue if you make it through debug console but it still wont update score.

```
lives = 3;
score = 0;
onEvent("button1", "click", function() {
if (getText("dropdown1") == "Easy Level") {
setScreen("easyFlagScreen1");
  } else if ((getText("dropdown1") == "Medium Level")) {
    setScreen("mediumFlagScreen1");
  } else if ((getText("dropdown1") == "Hard Level")) {
    setScreen("hardFlagScreen1");
  } else if ((getText("dropdown1") == "Master Level")) {
    setScreen("masterFlagScreen1");
  }
});
setScreen("startingScreen");
lives = 3;
score = 0;
  setText("lives1", lives);
  setText("score1", score);


//Easy Q1//
onEvent("chinaButton", "click", function() {
  score = score + 1;
  setText("score1", score);
  setScreen("easyFlagScreen2");
  setText("Lives2", lives);
});
onEvent("japanButton", "click", function() {
  if (lives > 1) {
    setScreen("easyFlagScreen2");
    lives = lives - 1;
    score = score;
    setText("lives2", lives);
    setText("score2", score);

  } else {
    setScreen("LoseScreen");
    setText("Score15", score);
  }
});
onEvent("southKoreaButton", "click", function() {
  if (lives > 1) {
    setScreen("easyFlagScreen2");
    lives = lives - 1;
    score = score;
    setText("lives2", lives);
    setText("score2", score);

  } else {
    setScreen("LoseScreen");
    setText("Score15", score);
  }
});
onEvent("northKoreaButton", "click", function() {
  if (lives > 1) {
    setScreen("easyFlagScreen2");
    lives = lives - 1;
    score = score;
    setText("lives2", lives);
    setText("score2", score);

  } else {
    setScreen("LoseScreen");
    setText("Score15", score);
  }
});

//Easy Q2//
onEvent("usaButton", "click", function() {
  score = score + 1;
  setText("score3", score);
  setText("lives3", lives);
});
onEvent("cubaButton", "click", function() {
  if (lives > 1) {
    setScreen("Wrong2");
    lives = lives - 1;
    score = score;
    setText("lives3", lives);
    setText("score3", score);

  } else {
    setScreen("LoseScreen");
    setText("Score15", score);
  }
});
onEvent("mexicoButton", "click", function() {
  if (lives > 1) {
    setScreen("Wrong2");
    lives = lives - 1;
    score = score;
    setText("lives3", lives);
    setText("score3", score);

  } else {
    setScreen("LoseScreen");
    setText("Score15", score);
  }
});
onEvent("canadaButton", "click", function() {
  if (lives > 1) {
    lives = lives - 1;
    score = score;
    setText("lives3", lives);
    setText("score3", score);

  } else {
    setScreen("LoseScreen");
    setText("Score15", score);
  }
});
```

Comment: can you include html as well

Comment: We r dumb we did not realize we had to make it update on next screen also the pause thing is gone somehow idk